# accessing specific columns from another table in the has_many/belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I have an `Rsvp` table which forms a join between a `User` and an `Event`. `Rsvp` table has information for an rsvp `status`. I need for `Event` to be able to access this info in the users/show view, perhaps make a call like `event.rsvp_status` as I showed below. User has freedom to change the rsvp status at anytime. How can this be achieved?
What my models look like:

```
class Rsvp < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { not_interested: 0, interested: 1, attending: 2 }

  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :user
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :users, through: :rsvps

  def title
    "#{self.name} with #{self.artists.map(&:name).join(", ")} at #{self.venue.name}"
  end
end

class User < ApplicaitonRecord
  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :events, through: :rsvps
end
```

I am using these methods in views for other models, such as `Venue`, `Event` and `Artist`

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def past_events
    self.events.select { |event| event.date < DateTime.now }
  end

  def future_events
    self.events.select { |event| event.date > DateTime.now }
  end
end
```

in the view, it would look something like this.

```
<%= "Upcoming events: " %>
  <% @user.future_events.each do |event| %>
    <% unless event.rsvp_status = "not_interested" %>
      <%= link_to event.title, event_path(event) %>
      <%= event.rsvp_status %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: So what have you tried? How do you think you'd pull out an rsvp that belongs to a particular event and a particular user?

Comment: I looked around the docs and some threads on here, didn't really find anything too relevant, just the simpler stuff like, in this case, Rsvp retrieving artist_id or event_id.

Comment: Ok, ignore the associations for a moment... Assume you need to `find` an `Rsvp` that belongs to a particular user and event - how would you do that in Rails? (Note: having taught this subject... I'm leading you to find the answer yourself rather than giving you the answer straight up because trust me, you'll learn so much more this way) :)

Comment: I can do something like `rsvp = @user.rsvps.where("event_id = #{event.id}")`, but then I still can't call `rsvp.status`, even though there's a column of that name in `Rsvps` table. The right record does get retrieved, however.

Comment: why does `rsvp.status` not work? It should if it's just a column... what error do you get? what would you expect to see? Also (sidenote): we greatly prefer you use: `.where(:event_id => event.id)` instead of the version you have (which uses string interpolation) as this way will make the SQL safer, whereas string interpolation doesn't.

Comment: there error I get: `undefined method 'status=' for #<Rsvp::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fabb403b8f0>`. it works if you do it directly like `Rsvp.find(:id).status`. also, changed the formatting.

Comment: Odd. `status=` means you're trying to set a value on the status... but that shouldn't be the case if you're just trying to look at the status... also AHA! `Rsvp::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` means that you've got a set of RSVPs, instead of a single one. what you probably want to do is add a `.first` on the end of your `where` - to make sure you've just got a single, actual rsvp, rather than a whole set of them (with just one in the set).

Comment: yes. without the `.first`, the format is not right. so with that addition and changing the operator from `=` to `==` in `unless event.rsvp_status = "not_interested"` it works. thank you for your help!

Comment: I'll make this mess into an answer for you to accept :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here error I get: `undefined method 'status=' for #<Rsvp::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fabb403b8f0>`. it works if you do it directly like `Rsvp.find(:id).status`

Odd. `status=` means you're trying to set a value on the status... but that shouldn't be the case if you're just trying to look at the status...

also AHA! `Rsvp::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` means that you've got a set of RSVPs, instead of a single one. What you probably want to do is add a `.first` on the end of your `where` - to make sure you've just got a single, actual rsvp, rather than a whole set of them (with just one in the set).

So that would mean the code would look a bit like this:

```
class User
  def rsvp_for_event(event)
    rsvps.where(:event_id => event.id).first
  end
end
```

and in your template:

```
<% @user.future_events.each do |event| %>
  <% rsvp_status = @user.rsvp_for_event(event).status %>
  <% unless rsvp_status = "not_interested" %>
    <%= link_to event.title, event_path(event) %>
    <%= rsvp_status %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

or something different, but giving the same end result :)

Thinking about it, an rsvp-scope might be prettier

```
class Event
  scope :for_event, ->(event) { where(:event_id => event.id) }
end
```

and in your template:

```
<% @user.future_events.each do |event| %>
  <% rsvp_status = @user.rsvp_for_event(event).status %>
  <% unless rsvp_status = "not_interested" %>
    <%= link_to event.title, event_path(event) %>
    <%= rsvp_status %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: great, my last question was gonna be if there is too much logic in the view file!

Comment: so, I have to uncheck this, because it's not a working solution. Sticking `        Rsvp.where(:event_id => event.id).first ` under a method in the User model, then calling it in the template like this `unless rsvp_for_event(event).status == "not_interested"` yields `undefined method 'rsvp_for_event' for #<#<Class:`. However putting it directly in the template like `rsvp = Rsvp.where(...` works fine.

Comment: Nah, the answer is a solution (we found your problem and you got a working solution out of it) - it's just got bugs in it. ;) I never guarantee that the code I supply is bug-free and always expect the original poster to work out their final codebase themselves (I'm not developing for you - you aren't paying my salary) ;) ;) However - this is the *kind* of approach you should work towards... if there's a bug in what I specifically wrote - why not figure out what it is so your solution works.

Comment: ok, fair enough, I asked for what approach to use - I got the answer. It's counterintuitive to check off an answer with buggy code, even if it helps me find direction to work in.

Comment: Don't forget that it's always plausible that the bug isn't in the code I supplied ;) It might be me... or it might be in how you applied it (maybe accidentally in the wrong place) or the value of `@user` that you're using isn't what you expected...  until you figure out what the bug actually is... beware of judging prematurely. I've looked over my code snippet and can't see anything obviously wrong. Certainly nothing that would count as "this method is undefined"...unless there's a typo I haven't spotted. but then, stack overflow doesn't have that kind of a spell-checker ;)

Comment: Ah wait I see - I hadn't spotted that you're using status before you get to the "display status" line... you just need to use a variable to store the value of status and use it in both places. I'll update to match